# How to deploy a cross project GCS event based cloud function in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, command-line-interface, airflow

I am new to GCP. I have 2 projects project1 & project2, there's a bucket called bucket-1 in project1 and I want to create a cloud function which triggers the Airflow DAGs in project2, which should run when we insert/modify the objects in the bucket-1.
Is there any procedure, script or CLI command to accomplish the task?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to write a function that listen the Cloud Storage event and that call Airflow API to run a DAG. There isn't out of the box solution, but piece of code that you can find, test and put together.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere , what you were saying is correct but the issue is the cloud function should be in project2 not in project1 and is there any way for cloud function to operate in cross projects for cloud storage event?

Answer (score 1):

To perform cross project event, especially with Cloud Storage, I recommend to do that:

- In the project1, create a [Cloud Storage notification to PubSub topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)
- In the project2, Deploy your cloud functions as a HTTP function
- In the project2, create a PubSub push subscription bind on the PubSub topic in the
  project1